# how can I get pgAdmin4 to open as a standalone desktop application on MacOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, postgresql, pgadmin

I recently installed Postgres and pgAdmin4 and in it's default it opens on the browser. On PC I was able to "force" it to open as desktop app by entering the path to Chrome in the configuration popup that appears up at the top of the browser window. However, this will not work on Mac the same way.

This is what I'm trying currently. To find the path I ran:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -i "google chrome"

which I found as the first answer in [this related thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95837/find-google-chrome-installation-directory-using-terminal?rq=1).
Am I accessing the wrong path?